# How to find where a library call returns?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, fortran

I am analyzing an external FORTRAN library which is quite huge. Anyways, the whole point of the library is to fit parameters values for a function I supply. The entry point is one method call with godzillion parameters.

The problem is, sometimes the call returns quite quickly, and the parameters values it spits out may as well have come from a random number generator. The question is: Is there any way in gdb (or some other debugger) to see where the return from the library method was called? I do have the sources and have already compiled them with `-g`. Btw, I use `g++` and `gfortran` for compilation. I can't go through the sources manually or execute it line by line, since the whole code is ~ `10k`lines of messy code.

One idea that came to my mind is to go through the source code and find all possible returns and set up breakpoints on all of them. But is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run gdb, type `help next` or `help nexti` and you can see the description of the `next` command which basically steps forward in your program.

What you can do is, set a breakpoint in the beginning of the function, and then from there, run the program step by step (using `next`) and see where it goes out of the function.

If the program is huge, you can binary search the return point. That is set a breakpoint in the beginning of the function and then from there type for example `next 500`. If you came out of the function, you stepped too many so start over and next time make a smaller step, for example `next 250`. If you were still in the function, you could step more and sum up your steps to know how far you went. So if you say another time `next 500` and you were out of the function, you start over and this time start with `next 750`. You get the idea.

Edit 1: Use `step` instead of `next` to go inside functions.

Edit 2: Try this see if it works:

Put a break in the beginning of the function and go inside it. Then (in gdb of course) type `finish` to run until function is finished. Then (this is the part I'm not sure if it would work correctly), type `reverse-step` and go backwards in the execution to see where the function had exited! (How cool is that?!)

Comment: In general, if you are searching for a command in gdb, simply run gdb and type `help`. It will give you a set of command categories. If your question is about running (like in this case), you choose the `running` category and type `help running`. Then it gives you the list of all commands with their short description which you can individually type `help <command>` and get the full description.

Comment: That should cut it. It's still more like stabbing in the dark, but if there's no simpler way...

Comment: It's not that bad, usually you don't really binary search, you look at the code and based on that get a good guess. Also, most of the times depending on where you land in the function, you can already guess where it would be going (that is, since you have the source code)

Comment: @dare2be One more thing, read my edit of the answer! If it works, that immediately solves your problem.

Comment: From the "correct answer" mark, I assume my second solution worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the -g3 -gdwarf-2 flags ? They may provide additional info for debugging.

Then you can step into each line of the program, but I don't know if it will work out of the box for a library